# Android : get cdmaDbm every second

Tags: java, android, networking

Just a simple question for you, as i couldn't find any info on that.
I just want to record the **CDMA signal strength** every one second.

Do you have any pointers?

I have found lots of examples, but they all use the `onSignalChange()` method which does not really work for me.

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to know this answer too.

Comment: There is really no way that I know of but the signal changes so much you could use onSignalStrengthsChanged just have to live with sometimes the signal won't change for a few...

Answer (score 2):

Well I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but after taking a look at the SignalStrength.java file in android source I noticed a bit of code that has a bunch of levels for cdma dbm and ecio levels.

```
DBM 
level 4 >= -75
level 3 >= -85
level 2 >= -95
level 1 >= -100

Ecio 
level 4 >= -90
level 3 >= -110
level 2 >= -130
level 1 >= -150
```

and level is the lowest of the two

```
actualLevel = (levelDbm < levelEcio) ? levelDbm : levelEcio;
```

but I noticed that this does not correlate to the actual bars showing in the notification.  If in 3G then this level is ignored and the Signal to Noise ratio is used.

```
signalStrength.getEvdoSnr() // value is 0 to 8 so divide by two to get the bars
```

if the data drops from 3G to 1x then use the actualLevel.

This was my code to find show the number of bars .

```
   public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
        if (signalStrength.isGsm()) {
            if (signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() != 99)
                signalStrengthValue = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() * 2 - 113;
            else
                signalStrengthValue = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
        } else {
            final int snr = signalStrength.getEvdoSnr();
            final int cdmaDbm = signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();
            final int cdmaEcio = signalStrength.getCdmaEcio();
            int levelDbm;
            int levelEcio;
            int level = 0;

            if (snr == -1) {
                if (cdmaDbm >= -75) levelDbm = 4;
                else if (cdmaDbm >= -85) levelDbm = 3;
                else if (cdmaDbm >= -95) levelDbm = 2;
                else if (cdmaDbm >= -100) levelDbm = 1;
                else levelDbm = 0;

                // Ec/Io are in dB*10
                if (cdmaEcio >= -90) levelEcio = 4;
                else if (cdmaEcio >= -110) levelEcio = 3;
                else if (cdmaEcio >= -130) levelEcio = 2;
                else if (cdmaEcio >= -150) levelEcio = 1;
                else levelEcio = 0;

                level = (levelDbm < levelEcio) ? levelDbm : levelEcio;
            } else {
                if (snr == 7 || snr == 8) level =4;
                else if (snr == 5 || snr == 6 ) level =3;
                else if (snr == 3 || snr == 4) level = 2;
                else if (snr ==1 || snr ==2) level =1;

            }

            text.setText("Bars= " + level);


        }
    }
```

in the on create method use this below, and also make sure manifest uses READ_PHONE_STATE.

```
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    AndroidPhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new AndroidPhoneStateListener(text);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
```

Comment: Props for reviving an old question

Comment: Thanks...was doing a search and found this old question thought it needed an answer.  Even though what he wants is next to impossible, unless you root and read the system files, I gave him the best alternative.